# Is it possible to set the PNG physical pixel dimensions using FabricJS?

Tags: png, fabricjs

The PNG specification includes physical pixel dimensions (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-png-961001#C.pHYs)).  Does Fabric.js support setting these values?  If so, how can these be set?

Edit: I should mention that I am trying to do this entirely in the browser.  I'm not using NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fabricJS does not support DPI values on output, but lucky enough i wrote a small library that will let you do that!

It works on blob and dataurl:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/changedpi

I know seems pure advertising but i think this piece of code will do that and it does just that, it works for both PNG and JPEG.

```js
// create the dataUrl at standard 72dpi
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.92);
var daurl150dpi = changeDpiDataUrl(dataUrl, 150);
```

or

```js
// create the blob at standard 72dpi
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  changeDpiBlob(blob, 300).then(function(blob){
    // use your changed blob
  })
},'image/jpeg', 0.92);
```

The method it uses here are not the one from fabricJS, for the dataUrl there is no problem since you can generate a dataurl and pass it to this function here, while for the blob you have to use

`fabricCanvas.toCanvasElement(...)`  then move from canvasElement to blob  if for any reason you prefer the blob advantages over dataUrls.